# How to setup routing tables to connect two subnets

Tags: networking, ip, routing

How do I setup my routing tables to allow traffic between two subnets

I have a gateway box with two NIC's

1st NIC [eth0] is connected to my outgoing network side and DSL modem and has subnet 192.168.0.0/24

2nd NIC [eth2] is connected to internal LAN and is on subnet 192.168.124.0/24

Obviously from the gateway box I can connect to everything but how do I allow machines from the 192.168.124 subnet connect to the 192.168.0 subnet?

Current tables are (obscured real world IPs):

```
[root@eagle:~]# ip route
***.***.***.151 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src ***.****.***.120
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.3  metric 1
192.168.124.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.124.1  metric 1
default dev ppp0  scope link
[root@eagle:~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
***.***.***.151 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
[root@eagle:~]#
```

Comment: This is a gateway and I have forwarding already set. What I want is a box on 192.168.124 to bet able to get to 192.168.0 which the gateway knows about. I guess I need rules on GW that most goes to inet except 192.168.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ipv4 only:
1) as root,

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

2) as root add the line

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

to the file /etc/sysctl.conf

3) advice: setup a firewall. Firestarter is a good start.